# How to run Docker and Docker-Compose from a Dockerized Jenkins container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose to run a Dockerized Jenkins container,

```
version: '2'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: 'jenkinsci/blueocean'
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
    user: 'root'
    ports:
      #host:container
      - '8888:8080'
    volumes:
      #host:container
      - /dati/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin:/usr/bin
      - /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

I'm able to run

```
docker ps
```

but not

```
docker-compose -v
```

which gives me `docker-compose: not found`.

However I'm able to list it from inside the container:

```
[root@dev-machine ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                               NAMES
d183202f2b2a        jenkinsci/blueocean                    "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"    15 hours ago        Up 15 hours             50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8888->8080/tcp   jenkins-compose_jenkins_1

[root@dev-machine ~]# whereis docker-compose
docker-compose: /usr/bin/docker-compose
[root@dev-machine ~]# docker exec -it d183202f2b2a sh
/ # ls -l /usr/bin/docker-compose
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 218 Oct 26 09:09 /usr/bin/docker-compose
/ #
```

I'm sure the user of Jenkins is root, as shown below from inside the container:

```
/ # whoami
root
```

What am I missing to make Docker-Compose work from inside a Dockerized Jenkins container?

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ - we managed it to use docker from within a dockerized jenkins using sibling

Comment: Sorry I just saw, that this is not recommended anymore. On our system it still works, but I think we also have to search for an alternative.

Comment: Yes, at least docker is working, even if it's needed to be root from inside the container. My problem is about `docker-compose`, which keeps saying `not found` even if it is bind mounted on `/usr/bin` and I'm able to list if from the container, and the mount of course is in the $PATH variable of the container.

Comment: Can you call docker-compose using the whole path?

Comment: Unluckly not.
`/usr/bin # docker-compose -v
sh: docker-compose: not found
/usr/bin # /usr/bin/docker-compose -v
sh: /usr/bin/docker-compose: not found
/usr/bin # sh /usr/bin/docker-compose -v
/usr/bin/docker-compose: line 4: import: not found
/usr/bin/docker-compose: line 5: import: not found
/usr/bin/docker-compose: line 7: from: not found
/usr/bin/docker-compose: line 10: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "then")`

Comment: You need to directly call it from within the directory- `./docker-compose -v` or `/usr/bin/docker-compose -v`
Nevertheless I also found out, that the docker-compose file needs to be located under `/usr/local/bin`.
How did you install docker-compose?

Comment: Neither this way.
`/usr/bin # ./docker-compose -v
sh: ./docker-compose: not found
/usr/bin #`

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?. I am stuck at the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Container in docker-compose file:
[image]

You should add this rows in docker-compose file.

Don't forget /usr/local/bin/docker-compose file is mustn't empty in your server machine.

Jenkins execute result:

[image]